# How to implement feature toggles on JS webapps running on the cloud

Tags: javascript, cloud, featuretoggle

I am by no means a JS developer, but I would like to get some background on what are the industry standards on this.

If I want to implement feature toggles to show, hide some features on a JS web app (for example Angular, but that should make no difference) running on the cloud, hosted by express/nginx. How do I go about implementing them?

The naive way would be to just implement a big map of feature_name => boolean, and if you want to enable and disable this then you need to change the boolean flag to true

My question is in a scenario, where you need to enable/disable features without rebuilding the application, assuming you work on a big firm, where config changes are allowed, but new deployments are hard.

In Java our feature toggles can just be overridden by env variables, but it seems that this is not that simple for web apps, so my question is what are the standards of doing this.